# Report Builder 3.0 - Hide or filter out the last/max value

Tags: reporting-services, filter, reportbuilder

The desired end result is to have a graph that, whenever generated, displays all the values except for the latest one. So if, at this point in my Dataset, my last period this year is 12, I want all the last year's and this year's periods to appear EXCEPT the last one being 12.

In fact, I have 3 fields: Year, Period and Delay.

Year is displayed simply as: 2017. There is a total of 13 periods and they are displayed as such: 01, 02, 03, [...], 13. To make things easier I created a field

```
 Fields!YearPeriod.Value =Fields!Year.Value+Fields!Period.Value
```

So now it, I can solely use 2 Fields and the YearPeriod one displays as follows(example): 201701. So this allows me to use the Max() function to isolate that last period that I am trying to exclude.

```
 Max(Fields!YearPeriod.Value)
```

Here is where I get stuck! I've tried using a Filter on my graph, but I get an error saying that filters can't have funcitons such as First, Last, Max, Min, etc. So I attempted instead to use the IIF in my graph value instead, (see below) but as soon as I generate, it shows me an entirely empty graph.:

```
=IIF(Fields!YearPeriod.Value=Max(Fields!YearPeriod.Value), Nothing, Fields!Delay.Value)
```

So, I tried using the Graph properties/Visibility section and I applied a similar function, but it's even worse: it makes the entire graph disappear all together...

It seems like a pretty straightforward thing to do but, finally, I'm definitely stuck. Thanks to all!

Comment: If you know that the current year 13 period is that one you want to filter out always, you can use in your filter something like this: `=IIF(Fields!YearPeriod.Value = CINT(Cstr(Today.Year) & "13"),Nothing,Fields!Delay.Value)`.

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks Alejandro, however, the current period changes overtime and the users, for who his report is intended, must have minimal input to generate it. Unfortunately, as well the Period field itself is not associated to a fix date either (changes annually)... I just tried another approach, I tried using the N inferior/Superior, but here's the outcome: with N Superior=1 it keeps (instead of excluding) the last Period. Whereas with N inferior, I need to indicate the number of Ns to keep, so I did Count()-1 but I get an error msg saying that aggregations can't be used in filters.. (X_X")

Comment: Are you using YearPeriod field in Category Groups of your chart?

Comment: @Alejandro Yup, to keep things simple, my only Category Group is Fields!YearPeriod.Value and my value is Fields!Delay.Value. Btw, I tried using RowNumber()-1 in my filter instead of Count()-1 and I get the same "aggregation not allowed" error. Basically, I need my filter to EXCLUDE the N Superior=1 value and not include as the filter is set by default... I found such a solution for NOT LIKE [=IIf(Not(Fields!XXXX.Value Like "TEST"), 0, 1)], I tried imitating this to no avail. Any suggestions with regard to this onyour end? Something like [IIF(Not(Fields!YearPeriod. Value N SUPERIOR 1), 0,1)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the filter in the Category Groups Properties instead of Chart Filter Property.

In the `Category Groups` Pane, right click `YearPeriod`, and select `Category Group Properties...`

[image]

In the Filter tab add a filter with these settings:

[image]

In `Value` use this expression:

```
=MAX(Fields!YearPeriod.Value,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of yours.

Aggregation functions don't work in chart Filter since there is no a scope (different to the whole dataset), that's is the reason that filtering the chart using MAX doesn't work.

**UPDATE:** Adding Year as Series in the Chart.

Add `Year` field to the `Series` pane in the `Chart Data` settings.

[image]

It will give you a line per `Year` value.

**UPDATE 2:** Use YearPeriod as `Category Group` but set the label as `Period`, also use `Year` in Series group.

You can set the label you want to be shown in the chart and it is not dependent on the Group field or expression you are using:

[image]

And in `Filter` use exactly the same expression I used previously. This is an example where I am hiding the last value for the last year (201713)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alejandro! Fantastic! It's the best solution so far!! What if my GroupCategory is Period only so instead of YearPeriod? (The purpose would be to have 1 serie per year, so 1 line 2016 and another 2017, otherwise by having YearPeriod as a GroupCategory I blend all the selected years together) I tried applying the same YearPeriod filter to Period (as a group category) but it removes that sepcific period for both series (2016 and 2017). Would you have any other great ideas like this one? Srry for pushing my luck, but thanks a lot!!

Comment: @MaxS., Try adding Year field to the Series pane in the chart as explained in the last edition to my answer.

Comment: I did exactly that: i.e. I kept Year in the Series Group. When applying the method in your desmonstration, it works fantastically when YearPeriod is the X-axis (Category Gp). But if I need to see 2 years Worth of data, I have 26 periods pop on that axis (13x2). However, say if I want 2 years of data on the graph and 13 periods on the X-axis, I have no choice but to have Period (Category Gp) & Year (Series Gp); however, by applying that same YearPeriod filter to Period, the targeted period disappears not only for the last year (as desired) but for all the years selected.

Comment: Thanks Alejandro!

Comment: @MaxS, you are welcome. if my answer solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to positively close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro's answer works very well as long as you don't mind having your series following each other instead of being superimposed.
I have found the following answer to allow this to work with the series being superimposed that works beautifully.

Here is what I mean by superimposed series and I have circled the data I don't want to show (i.e. the last period of the current year):
[image]

Here is my result:
[image]

**Solution:**
As we all know, filters normally don't allow aggregation which is the No. 1 reason why I had this problem to start off with. It wouldn't allow me.

So I found this link that details how one can "hard code" the ability to perform the aggregations sum, count, min, max and avg.
Long story short, I had to use max and this is how I did it:

1. copy/paste the code located at [Click here and, once on the page, click on "AggLookup.vb"](https://github.com/OzLocke/SSRSAggLookup) into your Code section in Report Properties
2. As in any LookUp function, find a Dimension using which you can Anchor 2 Datasets together and that allows you to regroup your targeted measure together. In my case, I went for the Name of the Hospital I work at and inserted that field into my Dataset1 and Dataset2. That allowed me to ensure that when I did the "max" function, it considered the 2015XX and 2016XX as being part of one group. Initially, I haven't done that and I used Year as my Anchor, which as a result filtered out the maximum value of each year: i.e. 201513 and 201613.
3. Go to the filter and create one using this tweeked LookUpSet formula:

> =code.AggLookup("aggregation", LookupSet([localValue], [matchValue], [returnValue], [dataset]))

**Make sure your aggregation is in small letters (no caps) and its surrounded by quotes, i.e. "**

I understand I probably took an awful long way around to get to my result, but saying I don't know much about SQL coding would be an overstatement. So I resorted to this option.